# Firebase Error: Auth error from APNS or Web Push Service

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

After running the following line in node-js:

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import * as serviceAccount from "../../firebase_service_account_key.json";

const app = admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount as any),
  databaseURL: "https://my-app-path.firebaseio.com"
});

admin.messaging().send({
    token: "known-good-token",
    notification: {
        title: "Test Push Note",
        body: "Here is some text"
    }
});
```

I'm getting the error:

```
Error: Auth error from APNS or Web Push Service 
Raw server response: 
"{
  "error":{
    "code":401,
    "message":"Auth error from APNS or Web Push Service",
    "status":"UNAUTHENTICATED",
    "details"[
      {
        "@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.firebase.fcm.v1.FcmError",
        "errorCode":"THIRD_PARTY_AUTH_ERROR"
      },
      {
        "@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.firebase.fcm.v1.ApnsError",
        "statusCode":403,
        "reason":"InvalidProviderToken"
      }
    ]
  }
}"
```

I've added an "APNs Authentication Key" to my ios project under the Settings > Cloud Messaging section of Firebase.  I've also properly downloaded and imported my service account json file.

In terms of research, I've tried looking up the errors.

- For the `InvalidProviderToken` error, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42549421/ios-sending-push-with-apns-auth-key-suddenly-403-forbidden-reasoninvalid) seems to indicate I'm using an old token.  This is totally possible, but the logs on my app and database appear to match, so it seems off.
- As for the `THIRD_PARTY_AUTH_ERROR`, google gave me no hits.  The closest thing I found was [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.auth.Error), and the following text might be the culprit (EDIT: it's not the issue):

> auth/unauthorized-domain
>
> Thrown if the app domain is not authorized for OAuth operations for your Firebase project. Edit the list of authorized domains from the Firebase console.

**Does anyone have anymore details on this error which might help me get to the bottom of it?**

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This error arises if your app setup for iOS has an error in any one of the following:

**Found in Settings > General > Your Apps > iOS Apps:**

- App Store ID
- Bundle ID
- Team ID

[image]

**When adding an APNs key (Uploading to Cloud Messaging > APNs Authentication Key):**

- Team ID (should auto set based off ios app info above)
- Key Id (often is in the name of the key, best to grab when creating it)

[image]

Comment: As an additional comment (b/c it took me a couple minutes to figure this out) you need to upload the APNs key you generate to Cloud Messaging => APNs Authentication Key

Comment: this post ends 3-4 days of desperately trying to display notifications for IOS with firebase in react-native - thank you sir you are an angel

Comment: In my specific case, I just renamed my bundle ID, but forgot to do that in Xcode. So the app ID, keys and APNs config in Firebase, Google Services file were all set up, but I only had to update the bundle ID in Xcode to make it work.

Comment: Expanding on @Franks comment.  If you have more than one ios app then you will need to upload the APNs Auth Key for each app here https://console.firebase.google.com/u/1/project/hivepass-dev/settings/cloudmessaging/

Comment: if you are confused like me about where you should create and upload the key , follow these steps

how to create key in apple console :
https://developer.apple.com/help/account/manage-keys/create-a-private-key 

where you should upload the key :
go to Firebase > select your app > select CloudMessaging tab in ProjectSettings > Apple app configuration > APNs Authentication Key > upload

Comment: In my case, my team ID was wrong. For those who don't know, the team ID can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/account.

Answer (score 6):

Everything worked for me the other day, so all setup was fine. But today  I got this error.

Here's what solved it for me:

1. Revoked APNs Key
2. Created new one and downloaded it
3. Deleted old one and Uploaded it to Firebase Dashboard / Settings /
   Cloud Messaging
4. Gone to Settings / Service Accounts and generated new private key
5. Added it to my Cloud Functions project (renamed it to
   service-account.json in my case)
6. Saved the files and deployed the functions: `firebase deploy --only
   functions`

Comment: hi, are your requests always sent failed or just few of them? i got the similar issue.

Comment: I too am curious if this issue came back after you did this.  It seems to happen on ~1% of requests I make the firebase services, I worry it's a longstanding error on their end.

Comment: Hi I tried this and it sadly didn't seem to work

Answer (score 1):

Did you call `admin.initializeApp()`?

There are many official samples.

See:

- https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/fcm-notifications/functions/index.js#L20
- https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications
- https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples
- https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/messaging

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The culprit was lowercase APNs teamId. Changing it to capital solved it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Double check **if you have uploaded your apns key on firebase console**. That was my case.

Answer (score 0):

If everything else fails, try creating new firebase project and setup push notifications for it.

For our purpose we only use firebase to send push notifications so this works. If you use it for anything else, you could separate the push notifications still to separate project and call it via [HTTP-requests](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1#after-endpoint) for example.

For some unknown reason one of our project fails on sending push notifications, it was fixed by re-creating the firebase-project.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to add in another reason why this might happen with ios specifically. They are upgrading to keys. So if you have certificates it might still work until may 2024 with you are debugging, but when launched it will fail to push the notifications.

in apple dev console  Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles->Keys->+  then check apns 
in the firebase ios upload that key and you will see a notice it will automatically disable certificates.