# how to get detailed errors from firebase cloud messeging?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, firebase-admin

I'm trying to send a message using APN over firebase and get the following message:

```
{"code":"messaging/third-party-auth-error","message":"Auth error from APNS or Web Push Service"}
```

How can I get the APNS error listed here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/ApnsError? I'm using the `firebase-admin` npm package.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your bundle identifiers in XCode and Firebase - it could be the simplest problem.

Follow this one [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56045461/13653284) to find the issue

Feel free to ask anything :3

Answer (score 0):

For me it meant that I have to renew APNS certificates in Firebase Console:

[image]